# Bootstrap 3.0 columns in a row moving into a new row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row with three columns.

- First one is size 1 offset 0,
- Second one is size 6 offset 1
- last one is size 1 offset 8

What expect to get is the following:

```
[Col1][Col2           ][Col3]
```

but instead I get:

```
[Col1][Col2           ]
[Col3]
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item itemlisting">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                        <img src="http://blog.bleepie.com/images/2010/05/week-16-logo-post-to-facebook/logo.png" class="img-rounded imglogo hidden-xs">
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1 middleColumn">
                        <h4>Software Developer</h4>
                         <p>Shell Corporation</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-8 col-md-1 col-md-offset-8">
                        <p>Calgary</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

This happens when I resize my screen to a width greater than 991px. I've been trying to play around with the offset and the column widths but I've had little luck with aligning everything correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 3):

cols - including offset cols - need to add up to 12. Your lg col set is adding up to 19. Switching the last col-lg-offset from 8 to 1 cleared the problem. See http://bootply.com/79908 or the code below.

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item itemlisting">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <img src="http://blog.bleepie.com/images/2010/05/week-16-logo-post-to-facebook/logo.png" class="img-rounded imglogo hidden-xs">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-8 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">
        <h4>Software Developer</h4>
        <p>Shell Corporation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-1 col-md-offset-8">
        <p>Calgary</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

PS - inline elements should not contain block elements, so wrapping all of those divs with an <a> goes against the spec. I don't think any browser will complain, it is just bad form.

PPS - I didn't bother to fix any of your md, sm, or xs cols either, so be sure to take a look at those and make sure you are staying =12 cols.

Comment: Regarding your comment with <a> being inline and should have not have block elements. VS does complain about that but as far as I know that's the only way one can turn a block element into a hyperlink. It's also the only way panels are [turned into links on bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-custom-content)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up with the column total. I edited my question. since I had copied the wrong html. My column total for lg does add up to less than 12. The reason the last column was flowing off the row was because of custom styling for other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't the offset classes in 2nd and 3rd divs. The content before these divs offsets it already.